# Permission denied error when installing pyttsx in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: software-installation

Permission denied error when installing pyttsx

```
pip install pyttsx
error: could not create '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pyttsx': Permission denied
```

Comment: Use `sudo pip install pyttsx`

Answer (score 1):

You have to be root or use sudo to go past that screen.

```
sudo pip install pyttsx
```

On my system:

```
parto@parto:~$ sudo pip install pyttsx
[sudo] password for parto: 
Downloading/unpacking pyttsx
  Downloading pyttsx-1.1.tar.gz
  Running setup.py (path:/tmp/pip_build_root/pyttsx/setup.py) egg_info for package pyttsx

Installing collected packages: pyttsx
  Running setup.py install for pyttsx

Successfully installed pyttsx
Cleaning up...
parto@parto:~$
```